# A p-adic analogue of a result due to Kirillov

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups, unitary-representations

Let $k$ be a non-Archimedean local field with char$(k)=0$.

Let $N$ be the group of $k-$rational points of a unipotent algebraic group defined over $k$.

It is known that $N$ is a locally compact and totally disconnected group. In fact, $N$ carries additional structure as a p-adic nilpotent Lie group.

In [1, Thm. 3, pg. 160] it is stated that Kirillov's construction of the unitary dual $\widehat{N}$ (i.e. the set of isomorphism classes of irreducible unitary representations of $N$) is essentially the same as the original construction for the unitary dual of connected and simply connected nilpotent real Lie groups.

I was wondering if another result of Kirillov, namely [2, Thm 6.1 (2)], also holds for $N$ as above. Let me restate the result for convenience:

> *Let $G$ be a connected and simply connected nilpotent real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$. Let $p:\mathfrak{g}^* \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}^*$ denote the canonical projection given by restriction of linear functionals. If $\xi$ is an irreducible unitary representation of $H$ with corresponding coadjoint orbit $\mathcal{O}_{\xi} \subset \mathfrak{h}^*$, then the unitary induction of $\xi$ to G is the direct integral of all irreducible unitary representations $\pi$ of $G$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{\pi} \cap p^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{\xi}) \neq \emptyset$ (where $\mathcal{O}_{\pi}\subset \mathfrak{g}^*$ is the coadjoint orbit corresponding to $\pi$).*

I believe that the aforementioned result also holds with $G=N$ and $H=exp(\mathfrak{h})$ for some Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. (I choose $H$ this way just to be safe, since I am not sure if closed subgroups of a p-adic Lie group are also p-adic Lie subgroups i.e. I don't know if Cartan's theorem holds in the p-adic setting).

However, the original result is a culmination of lemmas which sometimes rely upon connectedness arguments, but in our case $G=N$ is totally disconnected. So I am sure that a different approach (such as the one in [1]) based on p-adic analysis is needed in order to circumvent this.

I am not that much familiarized with p-adic analytic arguments in order to give a proof. Does anyone know if this is a standard result in the bibliography? If so, would you be so kind as to give me references? Otherwise, ideas for an argument would also be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**BIBLIOGRAPHY**

1 - C. C. Moore, *Decomposition of Unitary Representations Defined by Discrete Subgroups of Nilpotent
Groups*, Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 82, No. 1 (1965) pp. 146-182

2 - A. A. Kirillov, *Unitary Representations of Nilpotent Lie Groups*, Russ. Math. Surv. **17** 53 (1962)

Comment: Could you state the result you want to save everyone having to locate [2]?

Comment: @Simon Wadsley - I have now stated the original result, and also gave additional details about its adaptation to the current setting.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. I'm afraid I don't know the answer. But are you aware of https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2006-19-01/S0894-0347-05-00501-1/ by Jaikin-Zapirain and other work based on it?